# regex slightly greedy capture?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following possibilities:

1. `'  !This is a string! '`
2. `'!This is a string !'`
3. `'! This is a string !'`
4. `' ! This is a string! '`
5. `' !  This is a string    '`

In all of these case I want to match

`'This is a string'`

Heres what I tried so far:

```
/\s*!(.*)!{0,1}
/\s*!(.*?)!{0,1}
```

But it either gobbles up the `!` or doesn't match at all. Note that the `!` at the end is optional.

[**Here's a fiddle to see what I mean**](http://jsfiddle.net/UAefq/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure a couple of the answers below are correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or maybe this one

```regexp
/^\s*!\s*(.*?)\s*!?\s*$/
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. But efficiency can be improved slightly: `/^\s*!\s*(.*?)\s*(?:!\s*)?$/`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy my answer _from_ yours, it just ended up exactly the same after I edited it in response to refp's comment - guess I should've double-checked it against the other existing answers. No dispute that you posted it first. +1

Answer (score 1):

does this regex work for your problem?

```
^[\s!]*(\w*)[\s!]*$
```

Comment: Does this work?  I've tried it and it returned null.  Why was this upvoted? http://jsfiddle.net/UAefq/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(\b.*\b)
```

It uses \b which is [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UAefq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Will i be correct if i assume string can not contain !. In that case you can do something like:

```
/\s*![^!]*!{0,1}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one will keep the ! at the end:

```
/(?:^[^a-z0-9]*)(.*?)(?:\s*)$/i
```

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/UAefq/4/

It is also possible to update it to lose the ! and the spaces at the end of the string and that would look like this:

```
/(?:^[^a-z0-9]*)(.*?)(?:[\!\s]*)$/i
```

You can check the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/UAefq/5/

So I hope this answers your question completely.